# Python regex failing to extract a field

Tags: python, regex

I am having a problem with Python's regex:
My string looks like this:

```
NSLocalizedString(@"key", @"comment")
```

I want to extract key and I am trying with the following regex,

```
matches = re.match(r'NSLocalizedString\(@\"(\w+)\", @\"\w+\"\)', string)
print matches.group(0)
```

But the second line fails with: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Does anyone see a problem there?

**Edit**: The only thing I can see different is that NSLocalizedString(@"key", @"comment") is not the whole line, i.e. it's somewhere in the middle of the line.

Comment: Nope. I get `key`, with `matches.group(1)`. Can you show the actual code?

Comment: @thefourtheye but `matches.group(0)` must print the whole match. Instead of whole match, it returns an error.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes it does... It implicitly means that :-)

Comment: @Banana instead of white space , use `\s+`

Comment: Avinash is probably right, that this line contains whitespace other than a single space. Even if not, it's good to write the regex in a general way so it doesn't break.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me. Print the group index 1 to print all the characters from group index 1.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'NSLocalizedString(@"key", @"comment")'
>>> re.match(r'NSLocalizedString\(@\"(\w+)\", @\"\w+\"\)', s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 37), match='NSLocalizedString(@"key", @"comment")'>
>>> matches = re.match(r'NSLocalizedString\(@\"(\w+)\", @\"\w+\"\)', s)
>>> matches.group(0)
'NSLocalizedString(@"key", @"comment")'
>>> matches.group(1)
'key'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error ("AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'") is telling you that `matches = None`. You can get this one either a blank line, or a line not matching this format. So just add a line to test that the `matches` object is not `None`:

```
matches = re.match(r'NSLocalizedString\(@\"(\w+)\", @\"\w+\"\)', string)
if matches:
    print matches.group(0)
else: # if you want to debug
    print "Did not match on line:", string
```

By the way, don't name a variable to eclipse builtins or packages. Don't call it `string`, call it `s` or something.

Comment: This is not my problem, I know what my line must match the regex.

Comment: @Banana: when reality disagrees with a theory, the theory loses ;-) Variable `string` is not what you think it is then - show us the contents of `string`. By the way, don't name a variable to eclipse builtins or packages. Don't call a string `string`, or a list `list`...

Comment: Avinash is probably right, that this line contains whitespace other than a single space.